# How to check bcrypt password using jBcrypt? (move storage from Parse.com to Firebase)

Tags: java, parse-platform, cryptography, firebase, bcrypt

Some of developers need to move storage from parse.com to another servers.

When I exported my data from parse, I get json data. This json data has encrypted passwords (bcrypt) like:

> $2a$10$pcR4SaZd3PMD/nXQKMssxupMLncDoFwfU7avg/wdpLVChNqGOXbLu

I try to understand, how to check password from user in this case.

I using jBcrypt like this:

```
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String candidate = "$2a$10$pcR4SaZd3PMD/nXQKMssxupMLncDoFwfU7avg/wdpLVChNqGOXbLu";
        String password = "123";

        String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());

        if (BCrypt.checkpw(candidate, hashed)) {
            System.out.println("It matches");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("It does not match");
        }
    }
}
```

In this case passwords don't much. But if we go to https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator
and try to use BCrypt Tester with hashed, candidate strings and "123" password it's all ok.

How can I understand do user's password match with bcrypt string or not?

Comment: http://bcrypthashgenerator.apphb.com/ for testing too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BCrypt.checkpw()` takes a plain text password as it's first parameter, and will then hash it and compare it to the second parameter ([docs](http://www.mindrot.org/files/jBCrypt/jBCrypt-0.1-doc/BCrypt.html#checkpw(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))); in your case you're giving it an already hashed password as it's first parameter, which it will then hash again hence it not matching.